# Payment Integration Component in Salesforce Community (Napili Template)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili

We are creating a Salesforce community by using Napili template. In this community, we have a requirement to provide payment integration for product purchase.

Can someone suggest if there is an out-of-box (free) or 3rd party (Paid) components available for Payment Integration in SF community?

Thanks,

Ashish Shukla

Answer (score 1):

My company uses Zuora. Has a lot of payment gateways. Integrates with Salesforce or you can use their javascript approach to take payments.  https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/CA_Commerce/T_Hosted_Commerce_Pages/B_Payment_Pages_2.0